# Best way of getting related entity objects

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have 2 tables :

Table 1 called type has an id and a name
Table 2 called subtype has an id, a name and a typeId

TypeId is a reference to table 1 and a foreign key is created.

My objects :

```
public class BType
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Naam is verplicht")]
    public string Naam { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class SubType
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Naam is verplicht")]
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Type is verplicht")]
    public int TypeID { get; set; }

    private BType _Type = null;

    public BType Type
    {
        get {
            if (this._Type == null)
            {
                BTypeContext repo = new BTypeContext();
                this._Type = repo.BTypes.Where(x => x.Id == this.TypeID).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            return this._Type;
        }
    }

}
```

I'm not convinced that the way that i'm loading the type in subtype is the correct way.

In the view i need to create a table for the subtypes but i also need the information for the type for that subtype.

What's the best way to get the type info inside the subtype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your related Type **virtual** so that EF lazily loads related data
I've added ForeignKey attribute for clarity

```
public class SubType
{
  [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Naam is verplicht")]
  public string Naam { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Type is verplicht")]
  public int TypeID { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("TypeID")]
  public virtual BType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If i add this that i get the following error : There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

And do you know if this call is cached? e.g. i have 100 subtypes that are using the same type. 

Does it query only ones for the type and then caches it for the next calls? Or does it query 100x (for each subtype object).

Comment: Ignore the open Datareader: i've solved this by adding MultipleActiveResultSets=True in my connectionstring.